# Is there a tutorial on how to display search results using Actionscript 2 and Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have been looking for a tutorial that shows or explains how to display the contents of a search engine like 'Google' or 'Youtube' inside Flash. No luck so far...

Can any of you please forward a link or a good book that talks about the subject...?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go straight to the source.
[Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets)
should be able to search youtube from there. This is AS3, but it should give you a start.

Comment: OK, try this one then, based on the google code above:

var lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
lv.v = "1.0";
lv.q = "YOUR SEARCH IN HERE";
lv.onLoad = function(){
//decode JSON here
}
lv.sendAndLoad("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web",lv,"POST");